# Default constructor cannot handle exception type SAXException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java

I read similar posts but couldn't find the answer to my issues. I have written the below piece of code. I get the error:

> Cannot handle exception type thrown by implicit super constructor at line 3

**Code:**

```
public static String msg = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:sur=\"http://siebel.com/SurveyWebService\"><soapenv:Header><UsernameToken xmlns=\"http://siebel.com/webservices\">kchelamk</UsernameToken><PasswordText xmlns=\"http://siebel.com/webservices\">kchelamk</PasswordText><SessionType xmlns=\"http://siebel.com/webservices\">Stateless</SessionType></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><sur:QuerySurvey_Input><sur:SRNum>RFS-1-74143796</sur:SRNum><sur:AccountId>1-MPWH</sur:AccountId></sur:QuerySurvey_Input></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"; 
InputStream   input   = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes()); 
SOAPEnvelope  env     = new SOAPEnvelope(input);
```

Can anyone let me know what modification is required to my code?

Comment: Are you using `javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope` ?

Comment: I am using org.apache.axis.message.SOAPEnvelope. I tried with javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope But it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot handle exception type thrown by implicit super constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952692/cannot-handle-exception-type-thrown-by-implicit-super-constructor)